# LINQ: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to MVC and EF and LINQ.

I used EF and DB first to create all the models from the DB. I also created a ViewModel "CourseDetailsVM":

```
public class CourseDetailsVM
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryFk { get; set; }
    public int SoftwareFk { get; set; }
    public int TeacherFk { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public string CourseCodeMs { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseDescriptionShort { get; set; }
    public int CourseEventId { get; set; }
    public int? CourseEventDurationInDays { get; set; }
    public int? CourseEventPrice { get; set; }
    public int CourseEventDateId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CourseEventDateTimeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CourseEventDateTimeTo { get; set; }
}
```

In my Course Controller I try to get the Model from the Viewmodel using the following query (which works in linqpad but not in mvc) and I also use ViewData to access the repository (this works fine):

```
// GET: /Course/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        // get courses to display course details using ViewData
        ViewData["Courses"] = _repository.GetCourses(id);

        // get course events
        var result = (from c in db.Courses
                      join ce in db.CourseEvents
                      on c.CourseId equals ce.CourseFk
                      join ced in db.CourseEventDates
                      on ce.CourseEventId equals ced.CourseEventFk
                      group ce by new { ce.CourseEventId, c.CourseId, c.CourseCode, c.CourseName, ce.CourseEventPrice } into grp
                      select new CourseDetailsVM
                      {
                          CourseEventId = grp.Key.CourseEventId,
                          CourseId = grp.Key.CourseId,
                          CourseCode = grp.Key.CourseCode,
                          CourseEventDateTimeFrom = (from c2 in db.CourseEventDates where (c2.CourseEventFk.Equals(grp.Key.CourseEventId)) select c2.CourseEventDateTimeFrom).Min(),
                          CourseEventDateTimeTo = (from c2 in db.CourseEventDates where (c2.CourseEventFk.Equals(grp.Key.CourseEventId)) select c2.CourseEventDateTimeFrom).Max(),
                          CourseEventDurationInDays = (from c2 in db.CourseEventDates where (c2.CourseEventFk.Equals(grp.Key.CourseEventId)) select c2.CourseEventDateTimeFrom).Count() / 2,
                          CourseName = grp.Key.CourseName,
                          CourseEventPrice = grp.Key.CourseEventPrice,
                          CourseEventDateId = grp.Key.CourseEventId
                      }).OrderBy(c => c.CourseEventDateTimeFrom);

    return View("Details", result);
    }
```

Since Linq compiles on runtime, I can compile the project without any errors. But when accessing the Course/Details view I get the following error:
**Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.**

The error occurs when making an new instance of CourseDetailsVM on the following fields: `CourseEventDateTimeFrom, CourseEventDateTimeTo, CourseEventDurationInDays`

I tried fill the mentioned properties using hard coded values and it worked fine. So I know, where the error occurs, but I don't know why and how to solve it.

As requested by Yuliam Chandra, the content of the CourseEventDate class (generated by EF):

```
public partial class CourseEventDate
{
    public int CourseEventDateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseEventFk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CourseEventDateTimeFrom { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CourseEventDateTimeTo { get; set; }
    public virtual CourseEvent CourseEvent { get; set; }
}
```

I hope that sb of you guys can help me.

Thank you,

Ronin

Comment: what does your CourseEventD* fields look like in the database?

Comment: You are using `int?` which is not exactly int, but `Nullable<int>`. Is there a way you can convert this value to a normal int, or something else?

Comment: yes, I'm using int? and also DateTime?
If I change them to int and DateTime my code won't compile. Because the fields at the db are also nullable, I think.
e.g. when I'm changeing CourseEventDateTimeFrom to DateTime (not nullable) then I get the following error when trying to compile:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What is the type of c2.CourseEventFk?

Comment: CourseEventFk is INT NULL (nullable int), and so are all other FK (foreign keys)

Comment: Could you show the `CourseEventDate` class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error could be caused when comparing `CourseEventFk` (`int?`) and `CourseEventId` (`int`) using `Equals` where its parameter accepts object type which is a CLR method. LINQ to Entities doesn't support CLR method.

Try to use `==` operator, which somewhat compatible to L2S, on following code.

```
CourseEventDateTimeFrom = ..where (c2.CourseEventFk == grp.Key.CourseEventId)..
CourseEventDateTimeTo = ..where (c2.CourseEventFk == grp.Key.CourseEventId)..
CourseEventDurationInDays = ..where (c2.CourseEventFk == grp.Key.CourseEventId)..
```

Comment: seems as I'm not able to upvote because of my reputation being <15
sorry

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the past when I have encountered this kind of error was to create a static object (or anything that I needed at the given time) and did conversion myself such as following:

```
Private static double? myDoubleConversion(string sInput)
{
//conversion logic comes here

return result;
}
```

Comment: All this really does is sweep the problem under the carpet (if it even fixes it)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean..
The problem encounters when filling the following properties of a new CourseDetailsVM instance: CourseEventDateTimeFrom, CourseEventDateTimeTo, CourseEventDurationInDays
I'm not really converting anything, actually the data types should match.

Comment: It seems that CourseEventDurationInDays is not of the same type as you are pulling the data from....as based on the error it tries to convert object to int?

Comment: yes, that's true
like I said, I tried using hard coded values and no error was thrown
but how can I convert the return values of the subquerys to DateTime and Int?