# SQL to linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I try to fetch data from one table first I create sql query and then i try to convert this sql to linq query

```
  public static string GetVo()
    {
        try
        {
            TrackDataEntities1 DB = new TrackDataEntities1();
            var a = DB.tblVeh;
            string data = "[";
            foreach (var p in a)
            {
                data += "data:[";
                var re = (from vehvoila in DB.tblVeh
                          where vehvoila.MID.Equals("23065") && !(vehvoila.Name == "")
                          group vehvoila by new { vehvoila.Name } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              g.Key.Name,
                              cnt = g.Select(t => t.Name).Count()
                          }) ;


                data = data.Remove(data.Length - 1);
                data += "],";
            }

            data = data.Remove(data.Length - 1);

            data += "]";
            return data;
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }

    }
```

SQL query is

```
Select Name, count(*) from tblVeh
WHERE MID = 23065 and Name <> '' Group By Name
```

Data

```
VName (No column name)
d1     2
s2     1
f3      2
```

Now when I debug `data` shows

```
'[data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data:],data'
```

But I  want data like this

'['d1',2],['s2',1],['f3',2]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you looking for:

```
    public static string GetVo()
    {
        try
        {
            TrackDataEntities1 DB = new TrackDataEntities1();
            var result = DB.tblVeh.Where(x => x.MID == 23065 && x.Name != "")
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                  .Select(x => "['" + x.Key + "," + x.Count(y => y.Name != "") + "']")
                  .ToList();
            return String.Join(",", result);
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }
    }
```

Comment: i copy this in foreach loop ?

Comment: @user6408005 no, you don't need a foreach loop at all

Comment: @user6408005 `result` should contain your list

Comment: when i try this error occur ...Error 1 Delegate 'System.Func<chart_project.tblVehiclesVoilations_Uni,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments     Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type 
Error 3 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'string'

Comment: ok so we also need to return data or not.. because again error shows .. Error 2 'chart_project.WebForm1.GetVo()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: will you tell me why we can not use foreach loop?

Comment: @user6408005  we can, but we just don't need you in your case. Linq work with collections so you don't need to iterate manually

Comment: ok when  i add return following error occur.. = "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string' " –

Comment: @user6408005  you function return List<string> not string now

Comment: @user6408005 i update answer with full text of your function. It will work now how you expect

Comment: ok i add List<string> but when i set breakpoint this shows error on catch "DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types."

Comment: @what type your `MID` field? it's `string` or `int`?

Comment: MID is  int... and when i try your updated answer following errors.. Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string' 
Error 3 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]' 
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, params string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error :Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: @user6408005 then your field is not `int` try `x.MID.Equals(23065)`

Comment: i check db .. and type is MID is int type

Comment: @it's not int in your EF model since you got this error. Check it

Comment: public Nullable<global::System.Int32> MID
        {
            get
            {
                return _MID;
            }
            set
            {
                OnMasterIDChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("MID");
                _MID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("MID");
                OnMasterIDChanged();
            }
        }
        private Nullable<global::System.Int32> _MID;
        partial void OnMasterIDChanging(Nullable<global::System.Int32> value);
        partial void OnMIDChanged()

Comment: check this mid model

Comment: i can't say why you get error. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745922/linq-unable-to-cast-the-type-system-int32-to-type-system-object).

Comment: anyways will you tell me again why we can not use foreach loop

Comment: @user6408005 we can, but we just don't need. As i say already

Comment: why ? yes i know you told already but i did not understand why we can not use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114188/discussion-between-teo-van-kot-and-user6408005).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that should make you suspicious about your code is that the loop variable, `p`, isn't used anywhere. This sufficiently indicates that something is quite wrong. But also, you don't even use `re` anywhere. Doesn't Visual Studio do anything to indicate these flaws? (I'm so used to Resharper that I don't know what VS does without it).

The second thing that raises eyebrows is that you're weaving several responsibilities into one tangle of code. Getting data, grouping, building a string. Try to think in distinct steps.

Let's focus on separating the concerns of data shaping and formatting. First, you need grouped data (= data shaping). So do that first:

```
var groupedVehs = from vehvoila in DB.tblVeh
                  where vehvoila.MID == "23065"
                     && vehvoila.Name != ""
                  group vehvoila by vehvoila.Name into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Name = g.Key,
                      Count = g.Count()
                  });
```

Then focus on the formatting, for instance:

```
var stringOutput = string.Join(",",
                       groupedVehs.Select(x => string.Format("['{0}',{1}]", x.Name, x.Count)));
```

By doing this, it's much easier to change formatting later, or use completely different data with the same kind of format.